# Interpretation: Standard Error of the Estimate used in Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, dataset, standard-error, linear, trend

Is it true that the Standard Error (S or Sigma_est) of a Linear Regression removes variability imposed by the trend in the data, which the standard deviation does not?

[image]

Y is the Output, Y' is the predicted output from the regression and N is the sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't word the question quite as you intended.  No, the standard error of estimate does not "do" anything to variability; it is rather an indicator.  It tells more or less what is the typical magnitude of the error (or residual or disturbance) associated with each case in the regression.  Nor does a standard deviation, in and of itself, "remove" variability:  it too is an indicator.  Note also that the standard error of estimate is itself a type of standard deviation (of errors rather than of, say, an original distribution of a regression's X or Y variable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the world removes is not the right one in this case. 

But I meant that the Standard Error of the Estimate gives us the variability in the data points (the same as Std) but after removing the trend in data. Is that more correct?